# change the time zone from local to server time

Tags: node.js

I have a problem with the time of my app in the heat map area. The time must be taken from the server zone and not from the time of each device from which a user connects.
I live in a country with a -5 time zone and I have to manually subtract -5 from the hour. I would like the app to set the UTC server time.

```
const dateLimit = moment(new Date().toJSON(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').subtract(5, 'hours').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: Use  iso 8601 format or timestamp to handle time

Answer (score 0):

You can use UTC time. This will make the time consistent across all devices.
To set the dateLimit variable to the current UTC time rather than the device's time zone, you can use the moment.utc() function as follows:

```
const dateLimit = moment.utc(new Date().toJSON(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```